# Liquibase generateChangeLog not outputting schema

Tags: liquibase

When writing a changeSet for creating a table, you can specify the table's schema (see [here](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/create_table.html))

If I run

```
liquibase generateChangeLog
```

The output doesn't include a schema.

For reference, here's the liquibase.properties file I'm using:

```
driver: org.h2.Driver
classpath: h2-1.4.181.jar
url: jdbc:h2:~/test.db
username: sa
password: sa
changeLogFile: baseline.xml
liquibaseCatalogName: LIQUIBASE
liquibaseSchemaName: BAR
defaultSchemaName: BAR
outputDefaultSchema: true
outputDefaultCatalog: true
```

The output for one of the tables:

```
<createTable tableName="PRODUCTS">
  <column name="ID" type="INT(10)"/>
  <column name="CODE" type="VARCHAR(10)"/>
  <column name="PRICE" type="DECIMAL(9, 2)"/>
</createTable>
```

If I were to write this manually, I would include the schema:

```
<createTable schemaName="BAR" tableName="PRODUCTS">
  <column name="ID" type="INT(10)"/>
  <column name="CODE" type="VARCHAR(10)"/>
  <column name="PRICE" type="DECIMAL(9, 2)"/>
</createTable>
```

Is this by design? I'm OK with using an XSLT after the fact.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `--includeCatalog=true` flag after generateChangeLog. For example: `liquibase generateChangeLog --includeCatalog=true`

The outputDefaultSchema is only used if generateChangeLog should be including schema information in the first place.

Comment: It seems to actually require `--includeCatalog=true`; using `--include-schema=true` does not output anything

Comment: Sorry. Using includeCatalog vs includeSchema depends on the datatabase. I wasn't sure with h2 which it was off hand. I'll update the answer

Comment: Neither `--includeSchema=true` nor `--includeCatalog=true` worked for me. However `--outputDefaultSchema=true` did work

Comment: None of these work for me, I am connecting to a postgres database and using cli to execute the generatechangelog command

Answer (score 1):

Please use `outputDefaultSchema=true`. This will output the schema name in the changeset.
When using the maven plugin, please use `<outputDefaultSchema>true</outputDefaultSchema>`